# Can an error report include memory dumps from programs other than the crashed one?

Tags: 20.04, apport, privacy

If gedit crashes and I choose to send the error report from Ubuntu 20.04, will the memory state information in the error report only include gedit's memory or can the error report include memory dumps from other programs?

So basically I want to know whether the memory dump may include memory from other programs besides the crashed one.